# Оператор if в языках С/С++

Tags: c, c++

Мой друг работает программистом и у него часто возникают споры с сотрудником по поводу, что `if(a==b)` это тоже самое, что `if(b==a)`. Так ли это?

Answer (score 4):

Я не уверен, но думаю здесь всё зависит от классов **a** и **b** - точнее, от реализации оператора сравнения **==**. Например, в классе **A** он всегда возвращает *true*, в классе **B** - *false*. Тогда результат **a==b** и **b==a** будет разный.

Comment: Перегружаемые операторы - редкостное злодейство. За такое надо отстреливать серебряными пулями.. протёртыми чесноком :)

Comment: грамотно перегруженые операторы облегчают некоторые действия

Answer (score 4):

Нет, не всегда, простой пример:

```
std::string s = "a";

if (s == "a"){
    doSomething(); // works
}
if ("a" == s){
   doAnother(); // does not work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, результат вычисления выражения a == b в C и C++ не равен результату выражения b == a.  Например, a и b могут быть макросами:

```
#define a 0 || 1
#define b 1 && 0
```

Тогда получаются два выражения, результаты вычисления которых не равны

```
(0 || 1 == 1 && 0) != (1 && 0 == 0 || 1)
```

потому что оператор == имеет более высокий приоритет, чем операторы && и ||.

Comment: Вы показали прекрасный пример как макросы писать нельзя ни в коем случае. Правильный вариант - макрос заключить в скобки. Т.е. <code>#define a (0 ¦¦ 1)</code>

Comment: Не совсем по теме, Вы бы еще в качестве **a** и **b** взяли выражения, изменяющие свои операнды.

Answer (score 3):

Для встроенных типов и указателей a==b и b==a всегда одно и то же, для структур или классов зависит от реализации operator==. Оператор == должен быть симметричным, как обычно и делают. Если это не так, то скорее всего это ошибка, или создатель класса хотел всех запутать.

Answer (score 2):

Да, так.
Хотя, конечно, если `a` и `b` разных типов, то при этом может возникнуть коллизия при приведении к одному типу, например:

```
int a = 8;    
float b = 8.12381211;  
if (a == (int)b)   printf("a == b");  
if (b == (float)a) printf("b == a ");
```

При этом будет выполняться только первое условие.

Comment: Насчет коллизии согласен. Тут все сильно зависит от того приводимы ли типы друг к другу. Если нет - я думаю, что сигнатуры операторных функций для пар (a,b) и (b,a) будут разные... И, следовательно, результат выполнения тоже может быть разным. Правда, не представляю зачем это может понадобиться.

Comment: Такое обычно возникает совершенно случайно, когда определяют операции сравнения. А потом долго отлаживают:)

Comment: У меня MinGW Windows XP gcc и g++ оба не выполняются (как и следовало ожидать по правилам приведения типов в C, C++).

Answer (score 1):

Если **a** и **b** просто имена переменных то **в Си** (про плюсы не знаю) *почти* всегда if (a==b ) даст тот же результат, что и if (b==a).

***Почти*** относится к случаю, когда между двумя if отрабатывает обработчик сигнала (или thread), который меняет значение переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно не имеет разницы. Именно по этой причине для новичков есть рекомендация писать, скажем, не if(a==0); a if(0==a), это чтоб не путали = и ==. А вообще мне интересно, разве кто-то сравнивает тип float с типом int? Обычно оперируют переменными **одного** типа.

Comment: Ну, на равенство может и не сравнивают настолько разные типы как int и float, то на больше-меньше сравнивают точно. Но от этого суть работы с операторами не меняется.
Рекомендация, кстати не работает, если с обеих сторон оператора == стоят переменные. В случае с константой - да, возможно отловить ошибку.

Comment: Если все переменные проинициализированы,то порядок не имеет значения. Рекомендация приведена лишь для новичков, чтоб ошибки отлавливались *во время компиляции*.